# "looking forward to being". Is this correct?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

In order to convey excitement to being a part of a team, which one would you use?

> I’m so looking forward to **be** a part of [team name] that I can barely sleep.

or

> I’m so looking forward to **being** a part of [team name] that I can barely sleep.

Is any of these correct? If not, what would be the proper way of conveying this?

Comment: The latter, technically, is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking forward is always followed by the +ing (gerund).  A simple way to check this is to ask it in a question:  "What are you looking forward to?"  ...being part of the team.

I think if this were rephrased as, "I'm looking forward to being part of the team so much that I can barely sleep", might sound a bit more natural.

Comment: I’m not sure that question-asking helps all that much. It only works for native speakers and even then relies on possibly flawed memory.

Comment: Well, op's level seemed decently high by how that was worded.  But you could always just go with, "looking forward to" always requires verb+ing.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb *to look forward to* takes a gerund as its object, so the second version is correct.